# HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect returns to login page C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, response.redirect

This C# ASP.NET code sometimes fails to redirect. The result is that the browser is redirected back to the login page instead of mypage.aspx.

```
if (SuccessfulLogin)
{
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(UserName, RememberMe.Checked);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("mypage.aspx");
    return;
}
```

This works 99% of the time, but on some servers, it doesn't work. Is there an IIS setting I'm missing? Authentication issue?

Comment: There's not enough information here to answer your question. If your code works 99% of the time but fails on "some servers," you need to provide more information about the scenarios and manner in which you are encountering the failures. If you don't have that information, you need to investigate further. It is unlikely you will receive a quality response with only the information you have provided.

Answer (score 2):

You must enable "Forms Authentication" in IIS for this to work.

[image]

Comment: Glad you figured it out and followed up with the answer!